# How to index the "channels:*:users:*" keys in RedisSearch

Tags: python, redis

Need to index data in Redis.
But I can't find the right prefix to select all the necessary keys

I'm trying to create indexes:

```
class RedisClient:
    def __init__(self, settings: Config, db: int = None):
        self.settings = settings.redis_setting
        self.connection = redis.Redis(
            host=self.settings.REDIS_HOST,
            port=self.settings.REDIS_PORT,
            decode_responses=True,
            db=db if db is not None else 0
        )

    async def create_index(self):
        schema = (
            NumericField("$.channel_id", as_name="channel_id"),
            NumericField("$.events[*].event_id", as_name="event_id"),
            NumericField("$.events[*].timestamp", as_name="timestamp")
        )
        await self.connection.ft("idx:events").create_index(
            schema,
            definition=IndexDefinition(
                prefix=["channels:"],
                index_type=IndexType.JSON
            )
        )
```

But only the keys I don't need are indexed:
"channels:*", and the necessary "channels:*:users:*" are not indexed.
I tried:
prefix=["channels:*:users:*"]
But apparently the "*" operator cannot be used in prefix.

Comment: This looks like a feature request where there is wildcard matching of prefixes.  This is currently not supported.  Suggest to open a github issue on the redisearch repository and people upvote the issue there

Comment: Have you tried using FILTER with `exists` check? It might work

Comment: No, I haven't tried it, I'm not even familiar with this method, can you give more details?